# getclicky, woopra, track all pages?

Tags: analytics

How can I track all my website pages using those 2 web analytics apps? I can only track the first page, what shall I do? thanks.

Comment: Can you give us some more details about your website?

Comment: What kind of details are needed? It's a google app engine JAVA simple website. Some .JSP pages, nothing special.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the tracking code of each app on all your pages, not just your home page. Contact support at woopra.com, they'll help you set it up within hours.